# Data manipulation on a reactive event

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am creating a data frame, that is dynamically created when the user inputs a search term, in order to do this i have an action button, and the data frame is created when the "go" button is pressed.

Once this is done i need to perform various data manipulations on the DF, and out put different graphs.

i am struggling to understand how i do the data manipulation in Shiny, i have some simplified example code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(sp)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringi)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3),
    column( 4, 
            textInput("searchstring", 
                      label = "",
                      value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column( 12, tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("one",
               fluidRow(
                 column(3 ),
                 column(9,  plotOutput("ttext"))
               )
      ),    
      tabPanel("two"),
      tabPanel("three")
    )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tweet <- eventReactive(input$action,{
    num <- c(1,2,3,4,50)
    text <- c("this is love love something", "this is not hate hate hate something", "@something islove  rethched this not", " Shiny is love confusing me", "this is hate also somthing difficult")
    letter<- c("a", "b", "c", "D", "e")
    tweetdf <- data.frame(num, text, letter)
  })

  tdm <- if( is.null(tweetdf) ){return()}
  else{
    tweetdf$text <- tolower(tweetdf$text)
    # tweetdf @UserName
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove punctuation
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove links
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove tabs
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the beginning
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("^ ", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the end
    corpus <- iconv(tweetdf$text, to = "ASCII")
    corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
    cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
    tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
    tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
    w <- rowSums(tdm)
  }

    output$ttext <- renderPlot({ 
        library(RColorBrewer)
        barplot(w)

    })
    output$wordCl <- renderPlot({
      library(wordcloud2)
      w <- data.frame(names(w), w)
      colnames(w) <- c('word', 'freq')
      wordcloud2(w,
                 color = 'random-dark',
                 size = 0.7,
                 shape = 'circle',
                 rotateRatio = 0.5,
                 minSize = 1)
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

i keep getting the error message that tweetdf does not exist, This should not exist, until the user has entered a search term and clicked "go"

What is the best way to approach this problem, is this even the right spot to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you that tweetdf doest not exist because the result of eventReactive (tweetdf) is assign to the variable tweet, which makes tweet your actual reactive variable with the result of tweetdf in.

Also the problem in your code is that you mix classic variables with reactive variables.

You can access reactive variables by adding parenthesis at the end of the variable()

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(sp)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringi)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3),
    column( 4, 
            textInput("searchstring", 
                      label = "",
                      value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column( 12, tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("one",
               fluidRow(
                 column(3 ),
                 column(9,  plotOutput("ttext"))
               )
               # ,fluidRow(wordcloud2Output("wordCl"))
      ),    
      tabPanel("two"),
      tabPanel("three")
    )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  w <- eventReactive(input$action,{
    num <- c(1,2,3,4,50)
    text <- c("this is love love something", "this is not hate hate hate something", "@something islove  rethched this not", " Shiny is love confusing me", "this is hate also somthing difficult")
    letter<- c("a", "b", "c", "D", "e")
    tweetdf <- data.frame(num, text, letter)

    tdm <- if( is.null(tweetdf) ){return()} ## should not use return here as this is not a function
    else{
      print(tweetdf)
      tweetdf$text <- tolower(tweetdf$text)
      # tweetdf @UserName
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
      #remove punctuation
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tweetdf$text)
      #remove links
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove tabs
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove blank spaces at the beginning
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("^ ", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove blank spaces at the end
      corpus <- iconv(tweetdf$text, to = "ASCII")
      corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
      cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
    }

  })

  output$ttext <- renderPlot({ 
    barplot(w())
  })


  output$wordCl <- renderWordcloud2({
    w <- data.frame(names(w()), w())

    colnames(w) <- c('word', 'freq')

    wordcloud2(w,
               color = 'random-dark',
               size = 0.7,
               shape = 'circle',
               rotateRatio = 0.5,
               minSize = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @Junior Hechinger, I can see that you moved the data manipulation event in to the reactive event. The reason that i moved it out of the reactive event is that i want to perform many different manipulations to the DF each of which will be fed in to different graphs, i.e. wordcloud, network, chloropleth. so my question really is haw can i perform this complex data manipulation in shiny??? i really have no idea

Comment: You can perform complex data manipulation within a reactive variable and return results for different graphs. The straightforward way to do that would be that your reactive event do not only return a DF but a list of DF. Where each element of the list is the result of some computations. Another way to do it would be to use reactiveValues() that behaves like a list of reactive values.

Comment: Thank you for the directions you have provided, i believe this should send me down the right track.